# How to pass a variable value between background scripts in chrome extensions

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am developing a google chrome extension. I have a value set for a variable in one of my background javascript files(example.js). I need to access or pass this value to another backgound javascript file(extjs.js). How do I do it? Is there a global variable concept? I am not getting any error in my browser console.

my manifest.json

```
{
"name": "Example",
"version": "31.0.1650.57",
"manifest_version": 2,
"background":{
"scripts":["common.js","example.js","extjs.js"]
},
"content_scripts": [
{
"matches": ["<all_urls>"],
"js": ["myscript.js"]
}
]
}
```

my example.js

```
function trial()
{
/... some functionality../
var result = data;
}
```

my extjs.js

```
alert(result);
```

I know I am missing something.

Regards,
Nikhil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All background scripts share the same JS context, so any variable/function declared in one of the scripts is available to all the others (the order of loading plays a role of course).

When specifying one or more background scripts, Chrome automatically creates a minimal HTML page and inserts some `<script>` tags in the body. E.g. your automatically generated background page should look something like this:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <script src="common.js"></script>
        <script src="example.js"></script>
        <script src="extjs.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

You can take a look at your background page by navigating to `chrome://extensions` and checking the `Developer mode` checkbox. Then, under each extension there is link labelled "background page", which you can click to open a DevTools console of your background page.

---

**UPDATE:**

I just notice you are trying to access a function-local variable (defined in `trial()` function) from the global context (which is not possible).

Since `var result` is defined inside the `trial()` function, it is **not** accessible outside the scope of the function. (I.e. you won't be able to reference it from `example.js` either.)

You need to change your code like this:

**example.js:**

```
var outer_result = 0;
function trial() {
    var inner_result = 1;   // <-- this is a local variable
    outer_result = 2;       // <-- this is a global variable
}
// `inner_result` is undefined outside the function
```

**extjs.js:**

```
console.log(outer_result);   // <-- '0' since `trial()` is not invoked yet
console.log(inner_result);   // <-- 'undefined' since it is never defined

trial();   // <-- executing `trial()` function

console.log(inner_result);   // <-- 'undefined' since it is function-local
console.log(outer_result);   // <-- '2' since `trial()` modified it
```

Comment: You cannot use both `background:scripts` and `background_page` at the same time (nor do you need to). The manifest as posted in your question is perfectly fine and you should be able to access all functionality defined in `example.js` from `extjs.js` (which loaded after the former). In my answer, I do **not** propose to use an HTML `background_page` instead; I am merely pointing out that Chrome will generate one automatically for you (including the scripts you specify). Well, I just noticed you are trying to access a function-local variable from the global scope; I'll update my answer.

Comment: @nikhil: If you really liked the answer, feel free to upvote it as well ;)