# Accessing array in another JS file - Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Hi I am making a chrome extension for some practice that is a simple website blocker. I have two different JS files that are needing to share the same array that contains URLs to be blocked.

- background.js handles the webRequests and blocking websites
- options.html is the options page where users can edit URLs to be blocked, it calls storeURL.js so that it can store all the elements in the list on the html page into a js array. No problem so far.

However I cannot access the array inside of storeURL.js from background.js. It seems as if they are being called in two separate instances. If I try to include both storeURL.js and background.js inside of my background.html, that results in two totally separate storeURL.js scripts running.

How should I go about doing this? Should I store the array contents from storeURL.js into a file?

Some examples:

background.js

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
    blocking,["blocking"]);
    { urls: blockedURLS, types: [] }, ["blocking"]);
```

storeURL.js populates the array based on the list in options.html

```
var blockedURLS = [];
        $('li').each(function(i, elem) {
            blockedURLS.push($(elem).text());
        });
```

blockedURLS in my background.js appears as undefined. I have also tried to point my options.html file to background.js and just include all of the js in one file with the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="background.js"></script>
```

However when I do this it seems that a second background.js is called rather than just pointing to the one already running.

Feels like I've reached a dead end with possibly a simple solution that is available to fix my problem. I'm fairly new to JS/chrome extensions as well.

Thanks for taking the time to read this!

EDIT:
After some more fiddling I am able to access my blockedURL array in my background.js. However it is never updated.

```
var blockedURLS = ["hi"] ;

    var list = document.getElementById('list');
    $("#saveList").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        localStorage.setItem('todoList', list.innerHTML);
        alertify.success("You have saved your list.");

        //Pushes each element in the list from options.html into the urls array
        blockedURLS = [];
        $('li').each(function(i, elem) {
            blockedURLS.push($(elem).text());
        });
        alert("Currently blocked:\n" + blockedURLS);
    });
    $("#reset").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        localStorage.clear();
        location.reload();
    });

    loadToDo();

    function loadToDo() {
      if (localStorage.getItem('todoList')){
        list.innerHTML = localStorage.getItem('todoList'); 
    }
    }
```

What should be happening is that after I go into my options.html and save the list, "hi" should be replaced with all the different URLs I have in my list. However it is not. The blockedURL array is printed correctly in that alert though.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass a variable value between background scripts in chrome extensions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21012250/how-to-pass-a-variable-value-between-background-scripts-in-chrome-extensions)

Answer (score 0):

I haved to work with that kind of thing recently. I have never find a really good way to do... So I have used the Storage api of Chrome Extension API. But it's not really funny to use because all methods are asynchronus so you can't simply do

```
myValue = chrome.storage.local.get("MyValue")
```

If you want I have made an object that store data automatically in the chrome storage but allows simple and synchronus calls like `myValue = storage.myValue` or `storage.myValue = "something"`

[Here the github link](https://github.com/EmrysMyrddin/Chrome-Sync-Storage)

It was written in CoffeeScript so you can find javascript file in bin folder. The generated javascript is not very easy to read/modified but you can understand the idea simply by reading the CoffeeScript code I guess.

I can explain more how it works if you want. Tell me in comment and I will update my response.

And pay attention that it's a code I have written for my use so it's not the cleaner and bugless code that I have ever made :-) but it works fine.

EDIT : I have forget to says that you need to include this tow files in all pages / Content Script where you need to use it, of course.

Ho and sorry for my poor english... it's not actually my principal language ;-)

Comment: this is not recommended. Your method and library ignores the fact that a storage "set" can fail, and your library will continue to return the attempted set value (which later fails).

Comment: Yes, because like i said it's way to do this easily. If you have to check errors you can add a error handler fort example.

Comment: No because the error handler will run after you got the value using your library.

Comment: Yes, and You're script don't simply dire because of an error. It run with the old value and you can handle the error after. It's an other vision of handling error on distributed systems

Comment: And i prefere have a clean functional code with the normal flow and the error handling totaly separated

Comment: My main issue is that trying to change an async api to sync will have always issues. For example the library requires to read the entire storage on init even if you later only need to read or set a single value.

Comment: Yes you can't use this to store big amount of data.

Comment: And if the initialisation fail dit will never set the "initialized" flag

Comment: @EmrysMyrooin You can store unlimited data in `storage.local` if you request a permission.

Answer (score 0):

I had to use the following command:

```
var bg = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();
```

then I could access the blockedURLS array by:

```
alert(bg.blockedURLS);
```

and also edit the array by

```
chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().blockedURLS = [];
```

which would set it to an empty array.

Thanks guys for the help, it helped me in thinking of different possibilities on approaching this problem.

Comment: This is quite a crude method though; it couples your code very tightly. It might be better to use messaging/storage.